# how to write query to get that result

Tags: mysql

I have table named myTable contains some data like below

```
id type name
1   1    A
2   2    B
3   3    C
4   2    D
5   3    E
6   3    F
```

how to write query to get results like below id:name

```
type1  type2 type3
1:A     2:B   3:C
null    4:D   5:E
null    null  6:F
```

Answer (score 1):

Often, this type of operation is more easily done in the application layer.  However, you can do this by enumerating each row for each type and then aggregating by it.

I think this does what you want:

```
select max(case when type = 1 then concat_ws(':', id, type) end) as type1,
       max(case when type = 2 then concat_ws(':', id, type) end) as type2,
       max(case when type = 3 then concat_ws(':', id, type) end) as type3
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@t = type, @rn + 1,
                        if(@t := type, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from table t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @t := -1) vars
      order by type, id
     ) t
group by rn
```